# Page can’t be displayed on https

Tags: wcf, https

I got a WCF project that works in every computer in the company, but not on my pc.
I didn't wade any changes to the project.
Here is how the screen looks like after I run the project:
[image: WCF Test Client]

I can enter the site "http://localhost:52350/TSaveData.svc" and see the XML,
but when I'm trying to reach "https://localhost:44300/TSaveData.svc" I'm getting this screen:
[image: Page can't be displayed]

Here is the properties window of the project:
[image]

Web config part:

```
  <services>      
  <service name="WcfServiceSql.TSaveData" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">        
    <endpoint name="soap" address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceSql.ITSaveData" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITSaveData">
```

It is in needed format, like:

```
<services>
<service name="[Namespace].[service class name]">
```

More information will be provided on your request.

Please help me to get data from https://localhost:44300/TSaveData.svc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Reinstall the IIS Express.